# In C++11, how not to pass arguments to threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I am trying to implement the following code, but before accessing the memory corresponding to the pointer, I delete that memory in main thread.
Is this an undefined behavior, but the output is normal?

- Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.3)
- Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0
- Thread model: posix

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
void newThreadCallback(int *p)
{
    std::cout<<"Inside Thread 1 : p = "<<p<<std::endl;
    std::chrono::milliseconds dura(1500);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(dura);
    *p = 19;
    std::cout<<"Inside Thread 2 : *p = "<<*p<<std::endl;
}

void startNewThread2()
{
    int *p = new int(10);
    std::cout<<"Inside Main Thread : *p = "<<*p<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Inside Main Thread : p = "<<p<<std::endl;
    std::thread t(newThreadCallback, p);
    t.detach();
    delete p;
    p = NULL;
    //std::cout<<"Inside Main Thread : *p = "<<*p<<std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    startNewThread2();
    std::chrono::milliseconds dura(2000);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(dura);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
Inside Main Thread : *p = 10
Inside Main Thread : p = 0x7f7f765003a0
Inside Thread 1 : p = 0x7f7f765003a0
Inside Thread 2 : *p = 19
```

Comment: Output is normal doesn't mean absence of UB. In this case, I would say that it depends on the ordering. It is better to delete it in the thread that uses it. Or better yet, if shared ownership is desired, std::shared_ptr might be a good option. Also, setting to NULL does nothing.

Comment: I cannot make head or tail of the title to this question. Please improve it.

Comment: Try compiling your example with `-fsanitize=address` enabled, and it should complain when you run it about a use-after-free.  UB means you can't rely on the behaviour you're seeing:  Even though it works now, it is not guaranteed to work with every compiler and runtime you run it on.  It is also not guaranteed to break in the same way either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course that's undefined behavior.  You happened to get the correct behavior on some system, but you might not always be so "lucky."  An easy fix is to not pass raw pointers around (you could use `unique_ptr` here).

Comment: Thx, I got it!!

Comment: @TingfengXian: You're welcome.  If this answer solved your problem, you can "accept" it by clicking the checkmark on the left.  Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can reproduce the same behavior without threads - allocate some memory, write to it, free it and then read from it - in many cases you will read your expected value.

That's because during the `delete` operation the memory region is marked as "free" while it's contents remains untouched. So you will read the expected value from it until it's reallocated and written to someplace else in the program. There is no way to know when that will happen, which is partly why it's *undefined behavior*, i.e. don't do it.